# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\AttendanceSystem\resources\php\method.php on line 250

Tags: php, html

How to echo php variable in html that in String

```
$body = '<p style="font-size: 18px; line-height: 1.2; text-align:; word-break: break-word; mso-line-height-alt: 22px; margin: 0;"><span style="color: #2b303a; font-size: 18px;"><strong>Name: </strong><span style="font-size: 16px;">'echo $student_name'</span></span></p>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to echo it. You can just add it to the string since we're in PHP at that point:

```
'<span style="font-size: 16px;">' . esc_html( $student_name ) . '</span></span></p>'
```

You should also escape any variables you're adding to HTML strings using [esc_html()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html/) in case the strings contain HTML tags not just plain text.

Comment: @fuxia D'oh, thanks!

Comment: after update the code. This error occur. Do you know why?. Fatal error: Call to undefined function esc_html() in C:\xampp\htdocs\email\index.php on line 254

Comment: Oh, so this isn't actually WordPress? I guess you want [htmlspecialchars()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) instead then.

Comment: Not WordPress. And it works. Thank you